# Using Web API ODATA $expand=* for TPH entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, tph

The ODATA `$expand=*` term expands all properties of an entity. But in the TPH pattern, it expands only the base class reference properties:

```
public abstract class Person
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get; set; }

     public Place BirthPlace { get; set;}
}

public class Customer : Person
{
  public Job Job{get;set;}
}

public class Employee : Person
{
  public Post Post{get;set;}
}
```

Executing ODATA query: `/odata/Persons?$expand=*` only expands the `Place.BirthPlace` reference property; not the `Customer.Job` nor `Employee.Post`

But expanding a single entity works well as expected: `/odata/Persons(411)?$expand=*` expands `Place.BirthPlace` and either `Customer.Job` or `Employee.Post` based on the type of the entity

How to expand all referenced entities in the TPH scenario?